# Performance of GL_POINTS on modern hardware

Tags: opengl, 3d, gpu

Is there any difference in performance between drawing a scene with full triangles (GL_TRIANGLES) instead of just drawing their vertices (GL_POINTS), on modern hardware?

Where GL_POINTS is initialized like this:

```
glPointSize(1.0);
glDisable(GL_POINT_SMOOTH);
```

I have a somewhat low-end graphics card (9600gt) and drawing vertices-only can bring a 2x fps increase on certain sceneries. Not sure if it applies too on more recent gpus.

Comment: Considering that drawing points and drawing triangles are two completely different tasks that result in two completely different outcomes, I can't imagine the circumstances where you would be able to render the same scene as points or triangles based on some switch and still make sense of it.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't get it. I'm just asking for a very empirical statement. No less, no more.

Comment: OK, let me spell it out for you. If you believe that the answer would be useful to you *in any way, shape, or form*, you are mistaken. Any optimization you make based on that answer, any decision you make about how to build your graphics based on it, will be completely wrong.

Comment: @user2464424 True, it's just that there isn't much practical sense to it, given that the particular application decides if to draw points or triangles. In the end his comment was just that, a comment, nothing more.

Comment: idk how to put it. Take wireframe mode (GL_LINES). Which is good, useful and practical. Push it one step further: vertices only. Question: would it be a perfromance gain so that while in vertices-only mode I can display more objects?

Comment: @user2464424: "Push it one step further: vertices only"  ... aaaand that'll make it completely useless. Wireframe models are recognizeable with low number of lines/polygons, but to make user understand what the heck you're displaying as a point cloud, you'll need large number of points. Not worth it. Try displaying cube as pointclouud.

Comment: You have probably very badly written render code which collides with some bottleneck of your HW. How much triangles are we talking about? What fps (wanted and real)? Are you using  VBO or VAO (display lists and direct glBegin/glEnd are too slow for complex scenes)? You tagged also GPU so if you use shaders may be the bug is also there (from what you written it could be in vertex shader) what rendering are you using(textures,bump,lighting,reflectance...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if the number of triangles is similar to the number of their shared vertices (considering the glDrawElements rendering command being used) in both modes the geometry-wise part of the rendering pipeline will be evaluated at roughly the same speed. The only benefit you can get from drawing GL_POINTS relies solely on the percentage of empty screen space you get from not drawing faces, thus only at fragment shader level.

Answer (score 4):

> 2x fps increase on

You lose 98% of picture and get only 2x fps increase. That's not impressive. If you take into account that you should be able to easily render 300..500 fps on any decent hardware (with vsync disabled and minor optimizations), that's probably not worth it.

> Is there any difference in performance between drawing a scene with full triangles (GL_TRIANGLES) instead of just drawing their vertices (GL_POINTS), on modern hardware?

Well, if your scene has a LOT of alpha-blending and very "heavy" pixel shaders, then, obviously, displaying scene as point cloud will speed things up, because there's less pixels to fill.

On other hand, this kind of "optimization" will be completely useless for any practical task. I mean, if you're using blending and shaders, you probably wouldn't want to display your scene as pointlist in the first place, unless you're doing some kind of debug render (using `glPolygonMode`), and in case of debug render, you'll probably turn shaders off (because shaded/lit point will be hard to see) and disable lighting.

Even if you're using point sprites as particles or something, I'd stick with triangles - they give more control and do not have maximum size limit (compared to point sprites).

> I can display more objects?

If you want more objects, you should probably try to optimzie things elsewhere first. If you stop trying to draw invisible objects (outside of field of view, etc), that'll be a start that can improve performance.

> you have a mesh which is very far away from the camera. 1 million triangles and you know it is always in view. At this density ratio, triangles can't be bigger than a pixel,

When triangles are smaller than a pixel, and there are many of them, your mesh start looking like garbage and turns into pixelated mess of points. It will be ugly. Roughly same effect as when you disable mippimapping and texture filters and then render checkboard pattern. Using points instead of triangles might even aggravate effect.

: If you have 1mil triangle mesh that is always visible, you already need different kind of optimization. Reduce number of triangles (level of detail, dynamic tesselation or some solution that can simplify geometry on the fly), use bump mapping(maybe parallax mapping) to simulate extra geometry details that aren't even here, or even turn it into static background or a sprite. That'll work much better. Trying to render it using points will simply make it look ugly.

Comment: Ok, consider this: you have a mesh which is very far away from the camera. It is composed of 1 million triangles and you know it is always in view. At this density ratio, triangles can't be bigger than a pixel, thus GL_POINTS (w/ z-buffer) isn't going to impact image quality too much. Now, if I just draw the vertices of that mesh, can I have a gain in performance please?

Comment: @user2464424: When triangles are smaller than a pixel, and there are many of them, your mesh start looking like **** and turns into pixelated mess of points. It will be ugly. Roughly same effect as when you disable mippimapping and texture filters and then render checkboard pattern. Using points instead of triangles might even aggravate effect.

Comment: @user2464424: If you have 1mil triangle mesh that is always visible, you already need different kind of optimization. Reduce number of triangles (level of detail, dynamic tesselation or some solution that can simplify geometry on the fly), use bump mapping(maybe parallax mapping) to simulate extra geometry details that aren't even here, or even turn it into static background or a sprite. That'll work much better. Trying to render it using points will simply make it look ugly.